# Повествование или рассуждение?

Tags: стилистика

Помогите определить тип текста:
"900 дней продолжалась блокада Ленинграда, но устояли ленинградцы, разбили фашистов. Пришла в Ленинград победа."
В ответах (ЕГЭ) - повествование.
Только из-за того, что здесь глаголы?

Comment: Где этот ЕГЭ и кто автор ответа?

Comment: https://vk.com/doc197106329_556436876?hash=10ba0a5f72ea1b94a2&dl=3e693e2f7e082d98f1

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел исходный вопрос в неких тренировочных заданиях к ЕГЭ, но нигде не обнаружил ответ, в котором бы было сказано, что это именно повествование.
Вопрос звучит примерно так/

> Какое из утверждений верное:
> ....
> (список утверждений)
> ....
> Предложения (номер такой-то и такой-то) представляют из себя
> повествование.

Думаю, что это действительно пример повествования, что устанавливается просто методом исключения. Рассказывается о событии, никаких выводов или логических обоснований не дается. "Рассуждения" здесь явно не проходит, нет даже признаков какой-то логической цепочки, развития мысли...

Упоминания вами глаголов вообще не понял. Это не признак принадлежности к типу речи.

А вообще посмотрите здесь. Источник не авторитетный, но уж очень доходчиво (на мой взгляд) излагает.

https://bugaga.net.ru/ege/rus/theory/?n=30

Comment: там как раз про повествование очень скудно написано